# Hard drive bad sector appear more and more often

Tags: xubuntu, ssd, initramfs, fsck

I  have more and more often issues with my computer. I can't read some files sometimes when I use it for different tasks (developing, surfing, etc..). So I get the `initframs` menu when I reboot my computer. Then I just need to run

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

and then I'm be able to use my computer normally.

I usually encountered this issue on time per month. But now I encounter this issue average one time per days..

Is this mean I have to replace my hard drive? Or is it possible that a software corrupt some sector? Should I just reformat my hard drive and make a new fresh install?

I use Xubuntu 18.04 edition with an SSD.

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on your storage device.

Comment: Do you dual boot your machine with Windows also? If so, did you install a driver that allows you to read/modify files on the Ubuntu ext4 filesystem? If so, remove it asap, then fsck your Ubuntu partition, and you'll be fine.